# get a json property type with Newtonsoft Json

Tags: json, json.net, .net-core

I parsed a Json string with JObject.Parse(json) and I'm trying to traverse the properties. I find that the only way to access the json type is thru it's parent node, like this:

```
string json = @"{
    CPU: 'Intel',
    Drives: [ 'DVD read/writer', '500 gigabyte hard drive'
    ]
}";
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);

foreach (var p in o.Properties()) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("name:" + p.Name + ", value: " + p.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("o[p.Name].Type: " + o[p.Name].Type);  // correctly returns js type
    Console.WriteLine("p.Type: " + p.Type);  // returns Property for every item
    Console.WriteLine("p.GetType(): " + p.GetType()); // returns Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty for every item
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

I suppose there must be some way to get the json type from the property. (live fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aFFOPQ))

Comment: Did you try `p.Value.Type`?

Comment: You are right, please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Value` of a `JProperty` is a `JToken`.  You can use the `Type` property on a `JToken` to get its JSON type.  So you just need to use `p.Value.Type` to get what you are looking for.

Example fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CtuGGz

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    string json = @"
        {
          ""CPU"": ""Intel"",
          ""Integrated Graphics"": true,
          ""USB Ports"": 6,
          ""OS Version"": 7.1,
          ""Drives"": [
            ""DVD read/writer"",
            ""500 gigabyte hard drive""
          ]
        }";
    
    JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
    
    foreach (var p in o.Properties()) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("name: " + p.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("type: " + p.Value.Type);
        Console.WriteLine("value: " + p.Value);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: extra kudos for forking the fiddle ;-)))